# Block activity on TCP port within Node

Tags: node.js, tcp, v8

I want to block activity on a given TCP port within Node or if need be down in V8 in order to simulate disconnects in tests. I'd rather not disable network interfaces or get into firewalls for each platform so that testing can be consistent across platforms. I've tried digging through node source but haven't seen anything useful thus far.

Are there any public interfaces within Node or V8 that I could tap for these purposes?

======

Ultimately my question is as above, are there any interfaces that can be manipulated to disable TCP activity on a single port within a Node process. I think that could be generally useful for all sorts of tests, but my specific use case is as follows.

I need to simulate a disconnect on a long running PostgreSQL client `node-postgres` to ensure that my module successfully reconnects on subsequent retries once the port is again enabled.

Comment: Do you want to just block incoming traffic on the TCP connection while allowing the connection to appear to still be open (as if the other end just stopped communicating/responding)?  What do you want to have happen for traffic being sent out?  Remember, TCP is a positive acknowledgement transport so every packet sent out needs to get acknowledgement back or the socket will trigger an error (after some number of retransmission tries).  Or, do you want the TCP connection to actually drop and get closed?  Please be a lot more specific with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Drop and get close would be ideal, but ultimately anything that causes the client to receive an error rather than a completed response is sufficient.

Comment: Wait a minute.  So, you're trying to test the client, not the server?  If so, please edit the question to say that.  Questions should describe your actual objective, not just the problems your current implementation has.  Otherwise, we have no way of offering you solutions you haven't even thought of yet.

Comment: Can't you just kill the server process if you want to see how the client reacts when it loses its connection to the server?  Or unplug the ethernet connection to the server?  Or, in software, create a control port in your server (not accessible from the outside world) that you can send it a command to close all its client connections or close just a specific connection..

Comment: Perhaps you can just call `iptables` from within node to block activity on the port

Comment: For my use case I was able to accomplish the goal by locating and ending the underlying socket (i.e. `client.connection.stream.end()`). That still doesn't answer the question. I think it would be beneficial if there was some way to intervene with network activity within the Node process and would be surprised if there isn't, at least at the V8 level..